# how to convert an image into qrcode in android

Tags: android, image, base64

Actually, I'am developping an application wich should allow users to get photo from the camera and then convert it into qrcode.
I am trying to use xzing library to generate the qrcode and the Base64 java class to convert the image to String.But when I run this application, the class qrcodewriter handles an exception  indicating that the data is too big to be converted.I have tried to get some solutions to this problem and the only way that I found is to subdivise the String generated using the Base64 class into substrings and then convert each of these substrings to a subqrcode and finally concatenate  these subqrcodes to get the desired result.Can any one  help me to find  other method that is easier to implement.

Comment: Can you explain your actual end goal?  For example, are you trying to let other people see the pictures by scanning the QR code?  In that case, you would need to put the pictures online somewhere and then put the URL in the QR code.

Comment: yes this qrcode will be shared on facebook

Comment: the problem is that I am not able to generate the qrcode

Comment: You already described how you would generate the QR code.  What's the problem?  A photo is much too large to store in a single QR code.  If you insist on storing the data in the QR code itself, then there is no alternative to what you described.

Answer (score 0):

Try to resize and compress the image and then convert the compressed image to base64 encoding. This base64 string will be comparatively small. Now generate QR code based on this string. You have to find the trade-off between quality of image and it's size.